# Why doesn't this get characters?

Tags: c

Why does this `for` only runs 5 times? As in it gets 5 character and then stops. And if I change the `i<10` to `i<5` it only runs 3 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[1000];

int main()
{
    char a[100];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have named a global variable named same as a local one?

Comment: How do you know it gets only 5 (or 3) characters?

Comment: are you adding spaces between characters or newline?

Comment: @Breakpoint It does not produce the described behaviour.

Comment: @axiac right, it was just a general question not to answer or reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is most likely that you don't think the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will give you a character, but it will result in a newline `'\n'` character.

If you want to skip the newlines (or really *any* white-space) then use a leading space in the `scanf` format string:

```
scanf(" %c",&a[i]);
//     ^
// Note space here
```

If you want to read other space characters (like "normal" space or tab) then you need to use one of the character-reading functions like [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) or [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). For example as

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n')
        continue;  // Skip newline
    if (c == EOF)
        break;  // Error or "end of file"

    // Use the character...
}
```

Comment: @AjayKumar The thing is, the "thought" SPD has, is originated from a vast experience, not a wild guess.

Comment: @AjayKumar This is a perfectly valid answer. The question is incomplete but, based on their experience, some-programmer-dude makes an educated guess and I bet this answers the OP's question.

Comment: I understand, but i believed if we answer in questioner perspective then it would be efficient. as he might had to use his own code not yours for some reasons, possible YES. i just analysed in that way.

Comment: Yup, it works now. I had no clue about the enter character. Thank you very very much!